# DRF: callable in serializer choicefield "choices"

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have an admin serializer with an 'owner' field. I want the current users to populate the choices of this field, but when it comes to running migrations I get a TypeError, suggesting that drf doesnt support callables for the serializer choice field. django supports callables for the model choices field, but obviously the users change on the time, so I want this field to be populated on the serializer instantiation. Can anyone suggest a workable solution here?

```
def get_available_users():
    return [(u.id, u.username) for u in User.objects.all()]


class AdminCreateSerializer(CreateSerializer, AdminSerializer):
    owner = serializers.ChoiceField(choices=get_available_users)


>> TypeError: 'function' object is not iterable
```

Comment: Just to clarify, is the issue that you cannot run the tests, or cannot run the app as a whole?

Comment: Note: updated question with slightly different use-case (but same question applies) so Will's comment is no longer relevant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the solution here is to refactor and use DRF's PrimaryKeyRelatedField serializer  field (PrimaryKeyRelatedField may be used to represent the target of the relationship using its primary key.): https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#primarykeyrelatedfield

Answer (score 4):

To get your migrations to work

add

```
from django.utils.functional import lazy
```

then

```
owner = serializers.ChoiceField(choices=lazy(get_available_users, tuple)())
```

**or**

```
def get_available_users():
    try:
        _users = [(u.id, u.username) for u in User.objects.all()]
    except:
        _users = list(tuple())
    return _users
```

Comment: This is what I'm trying to avoid - when migrations are run it complains that auth_user table doesn't exit (as it doesn't!)

Comment: The error you are getting in your example is because you are not calling the function, but because you are setting choices to the function itself.

Comment: You cannot call the function directly, as when it comes to migrating a fresh database, the 'owner' field throws an error because the auth_user table doesn't yet exist. In django models, you can set the choices to a callable, but I'm illustrating that that doesn't work above - and asking for any alternatives.

Comment: https://chrisbartos.com/articles/i-have-a-choicefield-callable-that-includes-a-queryset-but-it-breaks-my-django-app/ this article illustrates the point. Basically, this doesn't appear to apply for drf choicefield, so looking for any suggestions.

Comment: sorry I keep making edits, it is late and I kept making mistakes

Answer (score 0):

Do the following:

```
User_detail = [(u.id, u.username) for u in User.objects.all()]

class AdminCreateSerializer(CreateSerializer, AdminSerializer):
    owner = serializers.ChoiceField(choices=User_detail)
```