# Django: Serializer raises exception in migration if model does not exist yet

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer, choicefield

I have this issue with django-rest-framework serializer where I have a choicefield that gets a list from a model/table. But when migrating the project for the first time it raises an exception. I've managed it for now using a try/except method but was wondering if there is maybe a better solution considering I would like to use more choicefields using data from a model query.

Bellow is what I currently have:

```
class FooSerializer(Serializer):
    try:
        bar = serializers.ChoiceField([foo.name for foo in Bar.objects.filter(active=True)], required=True)
    except Exception as error:
        handle_error(error)
        bar = serializers.ChoiceField([])
```

surely this can't be the best solution for handling an issue like this?

EDIT:
Tried maybe this method too:

```
from django.db.utils import OperationalError
try:
    bar = serializers.ChoiceField([foo.name for foo in Bar.objects.filter(active=True)], required=True)
except OperationalError:
    pass
```

Answer (score 1):

I have been fixing this problem by declaring the choices when initializing the serializer.
As you can see, I set the choices to be an empty array.

```
class SomeSerializer(Serializer):
    selection = serializers.ChoiceField(choices=[])

    def __init__(self, instance=None, data=empty, **kwargs):
        self.fields.fields['selection'].choices = MyModel.objects.all()
        super().__init__(instance, data, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that your inline Python code is not serializable during migrations as documented here: [serializing values](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/migrations/#serializing-values).

The work around might be to use a [functools.partial](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial) or partialmethod here, sometgin as in:

```py
from functools import partial

def get_choices(active=True):
    return [foo.name for foo in Bar.objects.filter(active=active)]

# ...

    bar = serializers.ChoiceField(partial(get_choices, True), required=True)
```

I haven't tested this code but used a very similar solution in my own project successfully before.

Comment: I can't seem to get this method to work either, I end up getting `TypeError: 'functools.partial' object is not iterable` on the console log.

Comment: Sorry to hear that; I have lost my solution as it didn't work for some other reason and I chose to keep the list empty in the serializer.

Comment: No worries. Hopefully someone will comment here with a fix for this. It's quite annoying and my method is to catch the error for now and return an empty list

Comment: just for future me: used `partial(get_choices, True)()` but back at square one again

Answer (score 0):

I had the same probleme with MultipleChoiceField. I found that [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50673949/drf-callable-in-serializer-choicefield-choices)

```
    ....
    def get_field_choices():
        try:
            _obj= [(obj.id, obj.serial_number)for obj in City.objects.all()]
        except:
            _obj = list(tuple())
        return _obj

            
    
    city= serializers.MultipleChoiceField(choices=get_field_choices())

    ....
```