# "No such table" error coming from serializers.py file, when running migration command

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I recently moved my Django app from using the default User model to a custom User model, and since this is not recommended to do mid-way through a project, I had to drop the database and migrations and recreate migrations and run migrate. This works fine when I comment out the entire serializers.py file, as well as comment out everywhere it is referred to. However, now that I want to be able to action all the new migration steps at production level WITHOUT having to comment out serializers.py.

I know that I have referenced a table that doesn't technically exist so, I'm just wondering what is the best way to do this? Here is my serializers.py code:

```
class MyModelSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
     features = Feature.objects.values_list("feature_name", flat=True) # Feature is a model
     feature = serializers.ChoiceField(features) # this is where the error happens
```

The error says: "no such table: myapp_feature"

Comment: What were the exact commands you used to "recreate migrations and run migrate"? Also, why did you have to recreate the migrations? You should generally keep the migration files after you first generate them.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice There are a lot of dependency issues involved when trying to switch to a custom user model midway through a project and the only way to solve this is by dropping the database and migration history and kind of "starting again" - check this ticket https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/25313 . However, that is beyond the question here I feel - and I don't remember commands exactly, but I deleted migrations, dropped db, ran "makemigrations" and then "migrate"

Comment: Check your `00001_initial.py` migration file. Does it have the code for the `Feature` model?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Yes, it does

Comment: I get that dropping the database is sometimes required. I do this in development all the time. I am always hesitant to do so in production, though. I find it strange that deleting migrations is also required.

Comment: So for some reason, the `myapp_feature` table wasn't created in your database. Did you double-check that it in fact doesn't exist in the database schema?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice None of the tables get created because "migrate" stops at an error. It is because (for some reason Idk), serializers.py references a table that doesn't exist YET - so I am guessing I've designed the code wrong in serializers.py but I'm not sure how to design it the correct way. The reason nothings gone wrong before is because the database has always existed...

Comment: oh right...because you are fetching all of the `Feature` objects in a class field. **That's** the problem you need to solve. You need to delay the `Feature.objects.values_list()` call.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django: Serializer raises exception in migration if model does not exist yet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64782942/django-serializer-raises-exception-in-migration-if-model-does-not-exist-yet)

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat yes i feel like that solution might work better for my needs, however I dont understand the "data=empty" part .. what is 'empty' ?

Comment: @Sorath `choices=[]`? `[]` is an empty list?